# Applying Itô's formula on trigonometric identity

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation

I have following issue on my hands:

> Use Ito's formula to compute the semimartingale
>   decomposition and the quadratic variation $[X_i]_t$ for $X_t= sin^2(B_t) + cos^2(B_t)$

This is quite strange, since we all know $sin^2(x) + cos^2(x)=1$. I think that this should apply also for Brownian motion. Hence, Ito's integral is:

$$X_t = 1 + \int_0^t0dB_t + 0.5\int_0^t0dt = 1$$

And the quadratic variation is then also $0$. I just want to make sure, that this makes sense, as I find this result quite odd. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain where $1.5c$ comes from?

Comment: I've edited my former post, but the $c$ comes from $\int 0dx=c$.

Comment: Those are definite integrals so you don't get the constants appearing.

Comment: oh, that's 100% true

Comment: You always have to pick a $c$, even for definite integrals. But then note $[f(x)+c]_{x=a}^{x=b}=(f(b)+c)-(f(a)+c)=f(b)-f(a)$ no matter what your choice of $c$ is. So we usually just pick $c=0$ for simplicity.

Comment: @MPW That's not true. You are only artificially introducing that $c$ because you are trying to define the definite integral in terms of an anti-derivative (or the indefinite integral). That is not how the definite integral is constructed. The definite integral is actually the fundamental object in terms of which the indefinite integral is defined.

Comment: @RhysSteele : Yes, that’s certainly true (+1 to you for that observation). But evaluating a definite integral in terms of antiderivatives is precisely the case to which I refer, perhaps I wasn’t clear about that

Comment: @RhysSteele : No. Selecting an antiderivative is, implicitly, selecting the constant. “No constant term” is just “$c =0$”. Consider the antiderivatives you naturally select for the identical integrands $(x+1)^2$ and $(x^2 +2x+1)$. Most would choose $\tfrac13(x+1)^3$ for the first and $\tfrac13x^3+x^2+x$ for the second. But the first of these antiderivatives expands to $\tfrac13x^3+x^2+x+\tfrac13$.

Comment: Sure, the point is that then your choice of constant is really nothing but a choice of anti-derivative with which to apply the fundamental theorem of Calculus. My point is that (i) this isn't necessary in the case of a $0$ integrand since you can evaluate the definite integral directly so doesn't apply here and (ii) risks losing clarity in the case of the Ito integral since you really shouldn't think of the Ito integral like an indefinite integral (though I suppose you can replace the FTC application with an application of Ito's lemma where you could replace $F$ with $F+c$ in a similar way)

Comment: @MPW you just responded to a comment that I posted then immediately deleted because I realised exactly the thing you said in your response. That comment now doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: Ok. I think we’re on the same page, thanks for an interesting discussion